# Functions incorporating a list and range:

Tags: function

Can someone send 2 examples where a 'list' and a 'range' is created,

Then each of them is brought down into a function and called.

So 2 functions,  1 example for each

Basic examples will be fine.

Comment: Please say what language you want to use or what tools you are already using to achieve this. Python can do 

`my_list = ["1", "11", "foo", "bar"]`
you can print all the items with 
`for item in my_list: 
    print(item)`

Comment: Can you tell me if you can use the range function inside another def() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range is a function which is available for example in python. Here I am generating a list using the range() function and printing every item in the list

```
my_list = [item for item in range(3,6)]
print(my_list)
for item in my_list:
  print(item)
```

if you "just" need the range functionality, you can also do

```
for item in range(3,6):
  print(item)
```

directly

if you want to make a function which uses the range function dynamically, you can do something like

```
def print_the_range(end_of_range):
  for item in range(0, end_of_range):
    print(item)
```

calling this function using print_the_range(15) will print all the numbers from 0 to 14. Please specify the language or your problem more specifically if you need any more help.

Comment: No problem, could you accept the answer so it doesnt show up as "open", if you have no more questions?